# How to check for string equality case insensitive in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a requirement where I need to check `DB/@dbtype` == 'oracle' (case insensitive). How can I do that?
Here is my code

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="DB/@dbtype">
        <p>
            <dd>
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>

                <xsl:if test="DB/@dbtype='ORACLE'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="DB/oracle_props">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                        <td valign="top" ><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </dd>
        </p>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="DB"/>                         
      </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I thought of converting it into all lowercase/uppercase and then check accordingly, so I used below

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:value-of select="translate(product/@name, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
<!--It display in lower case, but how to use this in checking for equality?-->
```

Please help me out, how to compare String (case insensitive way)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the same way:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(DB/@dbtype, $smallcase, $uppercase) = 'ORACLE'">
```

Answer (score 10):

Well if you're using XSLT 2.0+ then you can use

http://saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/lower-case.xml

i.e.

```
<xsl:if test="lower-case(product/@name)='oracle'">
  something
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:if test="translate(product/@name, $smallcase, $uppercase) = translate('Oracle', $smallcase, $uppercase)">
stuff
</xsl:if>
```