# XSLT 1.0 xsl:boolean choose test

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an object with data annotations for serialization. It has a boolean property which is true (tested with debugger) so 100% certain, but when I have this in the xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="order/Coupons/orderedCoupons" >
    <tr>
        <td>Discount <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@isperc='true'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@disvalue"/>%
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Epic fail
                    &#8364; <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@disvalue, '#.###,00', 'euro')" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It always displays **epic fail**, so the test always fails. I also have tried:

- @isperc='true'
- @isperc=1
- boolean(@isperc)
- @isperc = true()

some more background info: it is an asp.net object which I serialize with build in data annotations. The XSLT support in .Net is 1.0 only.

**edit** piece of my `coupon.cs`

```
[XmlAttribute("isperc")]
public bool IsPerc
{
    get { return _isPerc; }
}
```

it is not nullable, but as the 2nd commentor pointed out, what is the value of `<xsl:value-of select="@isperc"/>` well, it seems empty. it parses as nothing in the html. Not a whitespace, not null etc. that is strange because the boolean is `true`...

**edit2** this also outputs nothing `<xsl:value-of select="string(@isperc)"/>`, so this also fails `<xsl:when test="string(@isperc) = 'true'">`

Comment: Can you show an example of the input XML you're trying to process?

Comment: Have you eliminated a case issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940695/how-to-check-for-string-equality-case-insensitive-in-xsl. What does `<xsl:value-of select="@isperc" />` return?

Comment: You *must* provide the source XML document (as small as possible, please) and a complete XSLT transformation -- not only a fragment. Then anyone would be able to repro the issue and many people here can give a good solution. So, in the debugger, get the result of the serialization and place this XML document in the question. As it appears, this is a C# serialization issue and not an XSLT one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:when test="@IsPerc = true()">
```

should match a C# boolean type.

A workaround I've seen is to convert the boolean value to a number, though;

```
<xsl:when test="number(@IsPerc) > 0">
```

Comment: I will try, but the `XmlAttribute` is lowercase. `code` is also lowercase and as C# property `Code`. But I will give it a try and will update you a.s.a.p. thanks for your answer